# How to solve "SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares"?

Tags: python, pandas

I used this code to plot a graph and to fit it with polynomial fit. However, my data has some blank cells in excel data. That's why it is showing the error

"LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares

** On entry to DGELSD, parameter number  6 had an illegal value"

The code works if I don't have any blank cells. Can you please help me to solve this? How could the code be useful with a few blank cells in the excel data?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnEAK.png




#!/bin/bash
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xls = pd.ExcelFile('/UsersAll_My_Files/Projects/output_file/s_energy_lcto.xlsx')
name = pd.read_excel(xls, 'energy', skiprows=[0])
newname = name[['s', 'c', 'cm']]

p1 = np.polyfit(newname['s'], newname['c'], 2)
f1 = np.poly1d(p1)

p2 = np.polyfit(newname['s'], newname['cm'], 2)
f2 = np.poly1d(p2)

x= np.linspace(-0.055, 0.055, 100)



plt.plot(newname['s'], newname['c'], 'ro', label="C")
plt.plot(newname['s'], newname['cm'], 'gv', label="Cm")

plt.plot(x, f1(x), 'r')
plt.plot(x, f2(x), 'g')
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html / https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: Thank you.
I tried the following code to fit my data using polynomial fit. The code works if I have no empty cell in excel.
But I have few blank cells in my excel. That's why it is showing the error "LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares

** On entry to DGELSD, parameter number  6 had an illegal value". 

 But how can I solve it with few empty cells in my excel?